# Toggling fullscreen using the escape key in C# XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, fullscreen

right now I am working on a platformer type game and I am having difficulty exiting full screen mode using the escape key (Entering windowed mode). I've been all over the internet trying to find the solution, and I am as of yet to find anything that helps me.

It is one of the first things I am implementing into the game, so I don't have much code yet.

Constructor:

```
     graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        // screen size windowed
        if (IsFullScreenEnabled == false)
        {
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 730;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1000;
        }
        // fullscreen
        if (IsFullScreenEnabled == true)
        {
            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        }
        // mouse visible
        IsMouseVisible = true;
```

And here is the code for the escape key:

```
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read this and/or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsFullScreen` has no effect after screen setup.

During gameplay you should use `GraphicsDeviceManager.ToggleFullScreen`.

MSDN:

> Toggles between full screen and windowed mode. This method has no effect on the Xbox 360.

Replace

```
    graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

...with:

```
    graphics.ToggleFullScreen ();
```

...and as Bjarke mentions, you may want to ensure your guard for the above statement correctly checks the prior and current keyboard state to determine *was the key pressed and released* rather than just *is the key down* to avoid unwanted and repeated screen toggles.  Please refer to *[Detecting a Key Press](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*.

MSDN example:

```
    private void UpdateInput()
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
        // Is the SPACE key down?
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            // If not down last update, key has just been pressed.
            if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                backColor = 
                    new Color(backColor.R, backColor.G, (byte)~backColor.B);
            }
        }
       .
       .
       .
        // Update saved state.
        oldState = newState;
    }
```

This assumes your video card and/or driver is able to display 3D in a window.

### Tell me more

- [swiching between windowed and full screen](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/31773.aspx)

Comment: I've switched the IsFullScreen = false line in the escape code but it still refuses to work.

Comment: @CoderNoob See update. It may be that your driver is not able to do it

Comment: Heads up: You may want to add another check on that If statement that checks for the previous state of the keyboard. Otherwise you'll end up toggling fullscreen 60 times if you simply hold down Escape for just 1 second.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Thank-you.  Updated

Comment: Thanks guys, this has fixed it :)